# Ruby: object relation

Tags: ruby, class

I am working on a project involving object relations, and building classes that interact with each other through association.

Specifically, I am having problems with the .find_or_create_by_name method. This method finds or creates an artist by name, maintaining uniqueness of objects by name property. This works. 
The next part is it should create a new instance of Artist if none exists. This doesn't work.

```
class Artist
  attr_accessor :name, :song
  @@all = []

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @songs = []
  end

  def self.name=
    @name
  end

  def add_song(song)
    @songs << song
  end

  def songs
    @songs
  end

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def save
    self.class.all << self
  end

  def self.new_by_name(name)
    artist_name = Song.new(name)
    artist_name
  end

  def self.create_by_name(name = nil)
    artist = self.new_by_name(name)
    artist.save
    artist
  end

  def self.find_by_name(name = nil)
    @@all.detect{|x| x.name == name}
  end

  def self.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    if find_by_name(name) == nil
      create_by_name(name)
    else
      find_by_name(name)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Instead of `@@all` maybe use `def self.all; @all ||= []; end`.

Comment: Also `def self.name` is a class method, I'm guessing it needs to be removed.

Comment: You can also simplify `find_or_create_by_name` to `find_by_name(name) || create_by_name(name)`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

I went back and noticed that the .new_by_name method was creating a new Song instead of Artist. I changed that line to artist_name = Artist.new(name) and now that error no longer appears.

Here is the rest of the code with the changes you guys mentioned (thanks!):

```
class Artist
  attr_accessor :name, :song
  @@all = []

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @songs = []
  end


  def add_song(song)
    @songs << song
  end

  def songs
    @songs
  end

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def save
    self.class.all << self
  end

  def self.new_by_name(name)
    artist_name = Artist.new(name)
    artist_name
  end

  def self.create_by_name(name)
    artist = self.new_by_name(name)
    artist.save
    artist
  end

  def self.find_by_name(name)
    @@all.detect{|x| x.name == name}
  end

  def self.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    if self.find_by_name(name) == nil
      self.create_by_name(name)
    else
      self.find_by_name(name)
    end
  end

end
```